# Update docx metadata for a large number of files using python-docx

Tags: metadata, python-docx

I have about 300 docx files in folders and subfolders that I need to update metadata for. I have a separate 300+ line csv file containing the metadata: each row containing filename, keywords, title in rows.

I want to loop through the docx files pulling content from the csv and inserting the metadata into the docx files. Docx files are stored 2 sub folders down from the root folder.

So far, I have the following sketched out. What I am struggling with is figuring out how to loop through the csv file and apply the metadata to each file in sequence. I'm sure there is a relatively easy way to approach this, Setting up the loop and getting the csv content in is where I'm lost. I'm a noob, so kind of feeling my way as I go.

Any tips appreciated.

```
#running in python 3.5.2 32bit
import csv
from docx import Document
import os
import sys

csv_path = ("datasheet_metadata_uplift.csv")

def update_docx_metadata(document, keywords, title):
    """
    Update the *keywords*, and *title* metadata
    properties in *document*.
    """
    core_properties = document.core_properties
    core_properties.keywords = keywords
    core_properties.title = title

def read_csv_lines(filename, keywords, title):
    """
    Reads the csv lines, returns *filename*, *keywords*, *title*
    """
    with open(csv_path, 'r') as f:
        csv_file = csv.reader(f)
        for row in csv_file:
            filename = row[0]
            keywords = row[1]
            title = row[2]

def open_docx(filename):
     """
     Search for docx file and open it 
     """
     for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
         if filename in files:
            doc_path = os.path.join(path, filename)

csv_lines = read_csv_lines(filename, keywords, title)
for filename, keywords, title in csv_lines:
    document = Document(doc_path)
    update_doc_metadata(filename, keywords, title)
    document.save(doc_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

The next step I would recommend Aidan is to refactor your code into coherent functions. This will allow you to execute the required actions where needed, each with a single function call, such that intent and flow is not obscured.

You might start with something like this:

```
def update_doc_metadata(document, author, keywords, title, subject):
    """
    Update the *author*, *keywords*, *title*, and *subject* metadata
    properties in *document*.
    """
    core_properties = document.core_properties
    core_properties.author = author
    core_properties.keywords = keywords
    core_properties.title = title
    core_properties.subject = subject
```

Notice a few things:

- It's coherent, meaning it does all of only one thing. This makes is more reusable.
- It doesn't depend on anything that doesn't come in as a parameter. This makes it easy to test (if you did that) and generally easy to understand because all the context you need is in those ten lines.
- It has a docstring that states plainly what it does. This is a useful discipline not only because it helps a reader (most likely you, weeks or months later) understand the intent, but because it forces you to explain what you're doing. A lot of times you can detect a mis-factored function because it's hard or long to explain. (The asterisks around the parameters make them show up in italics in certain documentation packages.)

If you proceed like this, locating and "extracting" coherent bits into functions, the core logic of the main code will become much clearer.

I think the overall structure is something like this:

```
csv_lines = read_csv_lines(csv_path)
for filename, keywords, title in csv_lines:
    doc_path, document = open_docx(filename)
    update_doc_metadata(document, author, keywords, title, subject)
    document.save(doc_path)
```

Comment: Hi Scanny - thanks! Very helpful answer, I've been refactoring to use functions as you suggest, but something is not quite right. I get a `NameError: name 'filename' is not defined` error related to the final portion of the code. i've updated the original post with the new code.

any thoughts?

Comment: @Aidan I think you might be confused on the role of function parameters in Python. They get value(s) *into* a function, but generally not *out*. For that you need a return statement. So read_csv_lines should just take the csv_path as its parameter, then return a sequence (list probably) of (filename, keywords, title) sequences (maybe tuples). I think the return value of read_csv_lines is just `return [row for row in csv_file]`. You might want to find some of the Python tutorial resources. I like [this one](https://pymotw.com/3/) and the Python official tutorial is quite good too :)

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help scanny, i realized as much as i was looking at this today.

Comment: I can kind of see the logic of what i want to do, trying to express that in code is that hard part. I'll keep at it :)

Comment: @Aidan The mind, initially reluctant, will gradually bend to your will to code. In the fullness of time, you will think in code and not be able to remember what it was like not to :)

Comment: hahah, that's an awesome thought. i shall persevere. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So i figured this out, it ended up being quite simple. I also made it easier for myself by putting the full filepaths in the csv. thanks to scanny for the encouragement. next stop, the docs and tutorial pages :)

```
#runs in python 3.5.2 32-bit
#docx requires 32 bit operation
import csv
from docx import Document
import os
import sys

#path to the csv file - csv file must contain rows as follows:
#full filepath, title, subject
#ensure there are no commas, other than the csv delimiters

csv_path = "datasheet_metadata_uplift.csv"

#set up the lists that will be used to hold csv values 
filename = []
title = []
keywords = []

#sets up the csv file, and parses the "columns" to one of three lists: filename, title, keywords
f = open(csv_path)
csv_file = csv.reader(f)

#chops up csv into [] lists
for row in csv_file:
    filename.append(row[0])
    title.append(row[1])
    keywords.append(row[2])

#get the number of lines in the csv, and thus the number of files that need updating
file = open(csv_path)
num_lines = len(file.readlines())

#do the updates on every filename in the list
i = 0
while i < num_lines:
    if i < num_lines:
        #update the docx files, one for each csv file entry
        document = Document(filename[i])
        core_properties = document.core_properties
        core_properties.keywords = (keywords[i])
        core_properties.title = (title[i])
        core_properties.subject = ("YOUR_SUBJECT_HERE")
        core_properties.comments = (" ")
        core_properties.company = ("YOUR_COMPANY_HERE")
        document.save(filename[i])
        i+=1

print ("finished!")
```